# Do we need authentication credentials for TLS while sending mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send email using java mail api.
I'm using smtp.gmail.com server.
My question is do I have to provide username and password to authenticate this TLS connection or is it not really needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gmail SMTP server requires authentication. Pretty much every SMTP server does these days, to avoid being used as a spam relay.

You might find [this blog post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server) useful.